# Renomear arquivos para incluir um prefixo

Tags: javascript, node.js

Preciso resgatar alguns arquivos com um nome qualquer (Ex: "João") e renomeá-los incluindo um prefixo ("RJ-João").

Eu consegui listar porém não estou conseguindo renomear os arquivos:

```
const testFolder = './teste/';
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readdir(testFolder, (err, files) => {
  var arquivos = files.forEach(file => {
 
     console.log( files );
    
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer desta forma:

```js
const testFolder = './teste/';
const fs = require('fs');

const files = fs.readdirSync(testFolder);
const prefix = 'prefix'
files.forEach((file) => {
  fs.renameSync(`${testFolder}${file}`, `${testFolder}${prefix}${file}`)
});
```

Comment: Recomendo que explique o porquê de sua solução (ou como o código funciona) quando for responder uma pergunta para ajudar no entendimento de quem publicou o post inicialmente.

Answer (score 0):

Segue o código final.

```
const testeFolder = './test/'; // pasta de busca
const fs = require('fs');

const files = fs.readdirSync(testeFolder);  //lista todos os arquivos na pasta
var prefix = 'Teste - '; //prefixo
files.forEach((file)=>{
  fs.renameSync(`${testeFolder}${file}`, `${testeFolder}${prefix}${file}`) // pega o item com o nome antigo e coloca o prefixo

  // Remover o Prefixo

  //var remove = (file.replace("Teste - ", " ")); //busca a palavra

  //console.log(remove);
 //fs.renameSync(`${testeFolder}${file}`, `${testeFolder}${remove}`) // pega o item com o nome antigo e remove o prefixo
});
```